# what does it mean by "write an inductive definition for F as a set of pairs"?

Tags: propositional-calculus

> Give an inductive definition of the function F , defined by recursion on
>   PROP from the functions H at , H o, H ¬ , as a set F ∗ of pairs

Can anyone explain the question and give a hint for answer?

Comment: I'm afraid you're the one who needs to explain the question. Essentially all of its notation is probably specific to the (undisclosed) book (or notes) you have found it in, and there's no way for us to really guess what your book means by for example "H at, H o, H $\neg$".

Comment: this is the exact thing the book says. that's why I do do not understand it either